# OCaml - Mirror image of a tree

Tags: recursion, tree, ocaml

My tree type is

```
    type 'a tree = Tree of 'a * 'a tree list;;
```

How can I get the mirror image of a tree like this? For me is confusing having a list of children, because I do not know how to get individually to each child and do the recursion whitout losing the parent's track, any idea?

EDITED:
I have kept trying and I think I got the solution:

```
    let spec arbol =
         match arbol with
         Tree(a,[])-> Tree(a,[])
         | Tree(a,l)-> Tree(a, List.rev (
                  let rec aux = function
                      Tree(a,[])::[]->Tree(a,[])::[]
                      | Tree(a,[])::l-> [Tree(a,[])]@(aux l)
                      | Tree(a,t)::[]-> [Tree(a, (List.rev (aux t)))]
                      | Tree(a,t)::l-> [Tree(a, (List.rev (aux t)))]@(aux l)
                  in aux l));;
```

I have tried it with this tree:

```
let p = Tree(1, [
    Tree(2,[]);
    Tree(3, [
        Tree(6,[]);
        Tree(7,[])
        ]);
    Tree(4,[]);
    Tree(5,[])
]);;
```

And I got as result of `# spec p;;`

```
-: int tree = Tree (1, [
                Tree (5,[]); 
                Tree (4,[]); 
                Tree (3,[
                   Tree(7,[]); 
                   Tree(6,[])]); 
                Tree (2,[])
              ])
```

So I guess my function works as expected. Let me know if it is not correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the function you're trying to compute, there is a very simple answer that takes one line of code.

Unfortunately your code introduces so many cases that it's hard to check by eye.

It looks to me like your `aux` function is intended to calculate the mirror image of a list of trees. However, it doesn't work on an empty list. If you rewrite `aux` to work on an empty list, you might find that you won't require so many different cases. In particular, you could remove your outermost match and half the cases in your inner match.

In fact, your `aux` function (if correct) does all the work. If you look at it properly, you could just use `aux` for everything.

Since you're using `List.rev`, I assume you could also use `List.map`. That would be something to look at also.

**Update**

Trees are inherently recursive structures, so when looking for a tree algorithm, it often helps to imagine how you would use your algorithm recursively. In this case, you could ask yourself how you would put together mirror images of all the subtrees of a tree to make a mirror image of the whole tree.

Comment: I understand what you mean, actually I have rewrote it like this:

        `let spec tree = 
  let rec aux = function
             []->[]
             | Tree(a,t)::l-> [Tree(a, (List.rev (aux t)))]@(aux l)
           in List.hd (aux [tree]);; `

I think is much clearer and all cases are also consider. I'm looking at using `List.map` but I do not really know how to use it in my code.

Comment: You should really use `List.rev_map`. Then the function is the one-liner, `let rec spec (Tree (a,ts)) = Tree (a, List.rev_map spec ts)`

Comment: This is the solution I was talking about. But it might be better for OP to figure it out.